# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined at AthenaExpress.query

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect to AWS Athena and executing a select query. I used the **athena-express** package for this. Here is the following error.

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined
at AthenaExpress.query

```
Here is the sample code:
    
  const AthenaExpress = require("athena-express");
  const aws = require("aws-sdk");
  const awsCredentials = {
  accessKeyId: "AccesskeyHere",
  secretAccessKey: "secretkeyHere",
  region: "regionHere",
 };
 aws.config.update(awsCredentials);

 const athenaExpressConfig = { aws,getStats: true,s3:"s3URI" }; //configuring athena-express with aws sdk object
 const athenaExpress = new AthenaExpress(athenaExpressConfig);

(async () => {
    let query = {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM table where vin='123' and date like '%2021-08%'",
        db: "databasename"
    };

    try {
        let results = await athenaExpress.query(query);
        console.log(results);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
    
Here is the error:

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined
    at AthenaExpress.query 
    at async eval
```

Please let me know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

By using the pagination property I am able to get the resultset of the above

```
let query = {
 sql: "SELECT 1",
 db: "databasename",
 pagination: number
};
```

You can refer to this link to know more about the pagination:

https://github.com/ghdna/athena-express#more-examples